# Changing a string to integer in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, integer

My list looks like this:

```
print(dataset[0:2])
```

which gives:

```
[{'date': '13/09/2020', 'day': '13', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '35', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.3090878'}, {'date': '12/9/20', 'day': '12', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '34', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.22496971'}]
```

However I want to change the value in 'cases' and 'population2019' into integers instead of string.

I have used this code to change the string to integers

```
for i in dataset:        #Changes the value of multiple keys to integers instead of string 
    for key in i:
        i['cases'] = int(i['cases'])
        i['population2019'] = int(i['population2019'])
```

It does change the value of 'cases' to integer instead of string, but it doesn't work for 'population2019' since it is a big integer I suppose ('38041757').

The error is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: What are cases and populations2019 ? It seems that the problem is that you're trying to convert an empty string to an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine.As GProst said the error is coming because if i['cases'] or i['population2019'] is empty.Just add a condition before converting.

```
for i in dataset:        #Changes the value of multiple keys to integers instead of string 
    if i['cases'] != '':
        i['cases'] = int(i['cases'])
    if i['population2019'] != '':
        i['population2019'] = int(i['population2019'])
```

Comment: That's it! I forgot that one of them could be empty, thanks a lot!

Comment: `for key in i` is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have this error because `population2019` is an empty string ('') when you try to convert it

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

```
for i in dataset:         
    i['cases'] = int(i['cases']) if i['cases'] !='' else 0
    i['population2019'] = int(i['population2019']) if i['population2019']!='' else 0
```

Comment: It still says ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. I think the integer is just too big.

Comment: I made some change, can you try again please?
FYI The above part of the dataset works well for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dataset['cases'] = dataset['cases'].astype(int)
dataset['population2019'] = dataset['population2019'].astype(int)
```

I hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

there is an empty dictionary value for population in the data set as your code works without changing anything.[image: output] so  you can use error handling to stop your code from not running and changing almost all values like:

```
for i in dataset:        #Changes the value of multiple keys to integers instead of string
    for key in i:
        i['cases'] = int(i['cases'])
        if i['population2019']=='':
            i['population2019'] = int(2)
        else:
            i['population2019']=int(i['population2019'])
```

then you can find the value of population2019 empty by searching for a value '2'